# fetch api not working on chrome in macOS and iphones

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using fetch api to fetch some data from steam-web-api.And 'steam-web-api' does not allow fetch api to fetch the data directly from a asynchronous call.I must have a endpoint of my own in my backend which in-place goes and takes the data from steam-web-api.

So this is the code

```
  fetch(`/user/getGames?steam64=${dataObj.persondata.steamid}`,{
    method:"GET",
    headers:{
    'Content-Type':"application/json"
    }
  })
   .then(res=> res.json())
```

And this is the code for the endpoint in my backend

```
app.get("/user/getGames",(req,res)=>{
  const steamid = req.query.steam64;
  getGames(steamid).then((data)=>{ //async method which returns a promise with the fetched data from steam-web-api
    if(Array.isArray(data.response.games))res.json(data.response.games);
    else throw new Error("Games list private");
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    res.status(500).json(err.message);
  })
})
```

Please visit this link - [my website with the issue](https://mighty-citadel-31453.herokuapp.com/user?url=EaGL3_)

If your OS is windows and you are using chrome or firefox or brave.
The 'FRIENDS' and 'GAMES' sections works fine.

At the backend what i am doing is after the page loads im using fetch api to fetch the 'friends' and 'games' of a user from steam-web-api and load it asynchronously to reduce the load time as one might have thousands of friends which would take a long time.

'FRIENDS' and 'GAMES' are not working if your OS is macOS or you are using an iphone.

Comment: Just as a side note: It doesn't make any sense to send a `Content-Type` header with a GET request. The header specifies the content of the **body**, but a GET request has no body. (It **doesn't** define what the content type of the response will be.)

Comment: Yes thank you for the suggestion.Yes 'content type' must be used with fetch calls with a POST request

Comment: Right. My point was that the code in the question is sending it with a GET.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be a GET request.I have done a mistake in just adding the 'Content Type' header

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: No no error if i access the website from a android chrome or windows.I can see the heroku logs that the backend link is being accessed.But if the website is accessed from a macOS.There isnt even a log of the link being accessed in heroku logs

Comment: I just clicked your link and it seems to be working - I'm using Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: Could you please check if you have a iphone please @Matt Holland

Comment: I just accessed from my Mac and it works fine. Maybe you need a `fetch polyfill` for some browsers